# Include string (the name of imported file) into numeric array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I'm creating an array in my script (Matlab), collecting all the results I've calculated from a data file. Now, it would be nice, if I were able to include the filename in this array as well, for easy identification in later use.

What I've got now is (very simplified - cannot be run):

```
%Importing file:
FileName=uigetfile('*.CSV', 'Select .CSV-file','MultiSelect', 'off');
%Doing come calc on the data from the file imported...
%Results:
A=12;
B=4;
C=17;
D=124;
%Combining in array:
results=[A; B; C; D]
```

This works just fine.
Now, I want to include the FileName in this array:

```
results=[FileName; A; B; C; D]
```

This gives me the error:

`Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.`

Any ideas on how this can be solved? I'm quite a novice into this. I know it has something to do with the filename being a string (I've tried `cellstr(FileName)`, but it didn't help. Also, I've tried just `'FileName'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add an arbitrary string to a matrix of a specific size, this is mixing two types of data in a "container" that is not appropriate for both of them. To solve that issue you should save it as a [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) array or a cell array, that's how Matlab is designed to deal with these cases, for example:

```
results.name='Filename';
results.data=[A; B; C; D];
```

So you have a single variable `results` and can access the different type of data in it using it's field names, `results.name` etc....

EDIT:

For the purpose of moving this info to an excel file it is better to use a cell array:

```
your_xls_filename = 'bla.xlsx'; %$ just for the example
results = {'FileName'; A ; B ; C; D}; % this is a cell array
sheet = 1; % just for the example
xlRange = 'E1'; % just for the example
xlswrite(your_xls_filename,results,sheet,xlRange);
```

Now open `bla.xlsx` and see what you get.

Comment: Is it possible I can get the output in the command window as: FileName; A; B; C; D ? So I can easily copy and paste? Otherwise, it seems to be a solution I can live with!

Comment: it is possible, but I dont understand what you mean by easily copy and paste? what do you want to do with this information, paste it where?

Comment: Just into e.g. excel, so I can collect it (I've found this is the easiest way as I'm in a bit of time pressure, and don't got time for additional coding - and prefer this overview it provides me). So, I'll simply have a column of the filename and data and then copy+paste into excel. But I found `results.name,results.data` almost does the trick (with some additional lines when I mark it)...

Comment: you can do this automatically using `xlswrite`  where a cell array solves your problems, I'll edit it in the answer shortly

Comment: This is awesome! What a nice function! Thank you so much - this solves my problem!